# How do I call one method toString() thats defined in many subclasses in a main method to display polymorphism

Tags: java

Call a static method to display for EACH element the return the value of `toString()` and the return value of the `result()` method, but ONLY if the element isn't null.  If an element is null, display a message "Invalid Expression". YOU MUST USE AN ENHANCED FOR LOOP FOR TRAVERSING THE ARRAY.  You are NOT to check if an array element is a ArithValue, ArithBinaryExpression, AddExpression, SubExpression, etc.

So these are the directions of what I'm supposed to do. Basically I have an Interface called ArithExpression, and I have an abstract base class called ArithBinaryExpression which implements the ArithExpression. I also have AddExpression, SubExpression subclasses which extend ArithBinaryExpression. All the subclasses demonstrate polymorphism by overriding the `toString()`method. Now my problem is here: I do not know how to call one `toString()` method that will check for all the subclasses. This is an infix to arithmetic format program.

```
    public static void displayArith() {
            ArithExpression right;
            ArithExpression left;
            ArithBinaryExpression obj; // initialize this
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }
```

I have this code for the display function but it does not work and tells me that the `right` and `left` are uninitialized. I'd appreciate any help in the right direction.

**Here is the ArithBinaryExpression abstract class:**

```
public abstract class ArithBinaryExpression implements ArithExpression {
    protected static ArithExpression leftExpression;
    protected static ArithExpression rightExpression;

    // constructor
    public ArithBinaryExpression(ArithExpression left, ArithExpression right) {
        if (left == null) {
            leftExpression = new ArithValue(0);
        }

        if (right == null) {
            rightExpression = new ArithValue(0);
        }

        if (left != null && right != null) {
            leftExpression = left;
            rightExpression = right;
        }
    }
    // end constructor

    // accessors
    public ArithExpression getLeftExpression() {
        return leftExpression;
    }

    public ArithExpression getRightExpression() {
        return rightExpression;
    }

}
```

**And this is one of the subclasses:**

```
public static class AddExpression extends ArithBinaryExpression {
        public AddExpression(ArithExpression leftExp, ArithExpression rightExp) {
            super(leftExp, rightExp);
        }

        public double result() {
            double rightExp = getRightExpression().result();
            double leftExp = getLeftExpression().result();
            return rightExp + leftExp;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Expression: " + "(" + leftExpression.toString() + " + " + rightExpression.toString() + ")";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172960/discussion-on-question-by-rasul-imanov-how-do-i-call-one-method-tostring-thats).